# Exclude multiple file extension in xcopy

Tags: batch-file, cmd, xcopy

I have few extensions which I want to exclude from xcopy. I don't know in which folder/directory those may exist.

Below is the command I'm using:

```
xcopy /r /d /i /s /y C:\test1 C:\test2 /exclude:.txt+.exe
```

Anh help on this?

Comment: `xcopy` exclude switch only accept files from where to read the list of elements to exclude. Create the file or use `robocopy` and `/xf` switch

Comment: The `/EXCLUDE` option of `xcopy` does not really do what you want to, it does not exclude files with `.txt` and `.exe` extensions, it excludes all items whose full paths contain `.txt` or `.exe` at any position; for example, there is a source file `C:\test1\my.txt.files\file.ext`, it is going to be excluded also...

Comment: I agree with @aschipfl.  Would be safer to use a FOR command to list the files and use the command modifier to check if the extension is valid.

Answer (score 16):

What you are looking for is this:

```cmd
xcopy /R /D /I /S /Y /EXCLUDE:exclude.txt "C:\test1" "C:\test2"
```

Together with the following content of `exclude.txt`:

> ```cmd
> .txt
> .exe
> ```

However, the `/EXCLUDE` option of `xcopy` is very poor. It does not really exclude files with the given extensions, it actually excludes all items whose full paths contain `.txt` or `.exe` at any position. Supposing there is a source file `C:\test1\my.txt.files\file.ext`, it is going to be excluded also.

---

There are several methods to overcome this, some of which I want to show you:

1. Use the [`robocopy` command](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) and its `/XF` option:

   ```cmd
   robocopy "C:\test1" "C:\test2" /S /XO /XF "*.txt" "*.exe"
   ```
2. Create a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), using a [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html), together with `xcopy /L`, to pre-filter the files:

   ```cmd
   set /A "COUNT=0"
   for /F "delims=" %%F in ('
       rem/ // List files that would be copied without `/L`; remove summary line: ^& ^
           cd /D "C:\test1" ^&^& xcopy /L /R /D /I /S /Y "." "C:\test2" ^| find ".\"
   ') do (
       rem // Check file extension of each file:
       if /I not "%%~xF"==".txt" if /I not "%~xF"==".exe" (
           rem // Create destination directory, hide potential error messages:
           2> nul mkdir "C:\test2\%%~F\.."
           rem // Actually copy file, hide summary line:
           > nul copy /Y "C:\test1\%%~F" "C:\test2\%%~F" && (
               rem // Return currently copied file:
               set /A "COUNT+=1" & echo(%%~F
           ) || (
               rem // Return message in case an error occurred:
               >&2 echo ERROR: could not copy "%%~F"!
           )
       )
   )
   echo         %COUNT% file^(s^) copied.
   ```