# Exclude function is not working with xcopy

Tags: batch-file, cmd, window

here is my command

Exclude function is not working with xcopy

```
@Echo Off 
set source=C:\Users\garang\Documents\input_files2\Advisory_Rate
set destination=C:\Users\garang\Documents\input_files2\Advisory_Rate\Archive
xcopy "C:\Users\garang\Documents\input_files2\Advisory_Rate" "C:\Users\garang\Documents\input_files2\Advisory_Rate\Archive" /S /C /Y /EXCLUDE:"C:\Users\garang\Documents\input_files2\Advisory_Rate\Advisory Rate mapping.xlsx"
```

error:

```
C:\Users\garang\Documents\input_files2\Advisory_Rate>movefiles 
Can't read file: "C:\Users\garang\Documents\input_files2\Advisory_Rate\Advisory Rate mapping.xlsx" 
0 File(s) copied 
C:\Users\garang\Documents\input_files2\Advisory_Rate>
```

**Here is the [reference question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50796886/6738015), I have abandoned for this question.**

Comment: What's the point of providing code and errors in comments? Please post them in the question by [edit]ing your post and [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) them properly! Make sure the code is a [mcve]! Furthermore, read the [tour] and learn [ask] here!

Comment: what makes you think, `xcopy` can read `XLSX` files? Use a plain text file instead. (`.csv` would be ok, because `.csv` *is*  plain text)

Comment: understand but the requirement is to move all .xlsx files to archive folder except  2 excel files

Comment: @RupeshShelar, did you read the help file?  It is pretty clear how the exclude option works.  You need to put your excludes inside a text file.

Comment: I have added a [reference footnote](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50796886/6738015) to your question, to prevent people from repeating the advice I've already provided you.

Comment: @RupeshShelar, open a new text file. On line `1`, put the filename of the first `.xlsx` file you don't want to copy; On line `2` put the filename of the other `.xlsx` file you don't want to copy; Save the file as `ExcludeUs.txt`. Put `ExcludeUs.txt` in the same location as your batch file/current directory, change the `XCopy` command to `XCopy "%source%" "%destination%" /S /C /Y /EXCLUDE:ExcludeUs.txt`; and run the batch file!

Comment: As others already pointed out, `/EXCLUDE` option expects a text file that contains (partial) paths to exclude. The path to the text file must not contain white-spaces or special characters and must not be put in quotes; otherwise it fails. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42399461) to learn more...

Comment: working ...@Echo Off
set source=C:\Users\garang\Documents\input_files2\Advisory_Rate
set destination=C:\Users\garang\Documents\input_files2\Advisory_Rate\Archi
ROBOCOPY C:\Users\garang\Documents\input_files2\Advisory_Rate  C:\Users\garang\Documents\input_files2\Advisory_Rate\Archive\  /XF C:\Users\garang\Documents\input_files2\Advisory_Rate\Quick_OPU_listing.xlsx

Comment: i wanted to move the files  and exclude the two files command instead of robocopy

Comment: @RupeshShelar, please do not put that much code into a comment. You should edit your question with that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RoboCopy` can move files and directories too!!

If you have just that one directory named `Archive` in that particular tree you could probably use this:

```bat
@CD /D "%UserProfile%\Documents\input_files2\Advisory_Rate" 2>Nul || Exit /B
@RoboCopy . Archive /S /Move /XD "Archive" /XF "Advisory Rate mapping.xlsx" "Quick_OPU_listing.xlsx" 2>Nul
```

Comment: Hi Compo, i fixed all this only thing is i wanted to exclude this Advisory_Rate folder from your earlier query...please help me with last step+++++++++++++++++++++++++@Echo Off
Set "dirSrc=C:\Users\garang\Documents\input_files"
Set "dirDst=Archive"
Set "extSrc=*.xlsx"
CD /D "%dirSrc%" 2>Nul || Exit /B
For /D %%A In (*) Do (PushD "%%A"
    For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%B In (
        'Dir /B/A-D-H-L-S/O-D/TW "%extSrc%" 2^>Nul') Do (
        If Not Exist "%dirDst%\" MD "%dirDst%"
        Move /Y "%%B" "%dirDst%">Nul 2>&1)
    PopD)

Comment: @RupeshShelar, my first comment in the reference question answered the your initial query on skipping a directory, as did the advice both here and in that reference topic on the usage of `XCopy`'s `/Exclude` with directory names and `RoboCopy`'s `/XD` option. This site is not a free code request service, an interactive search facility or a one to one private tutor service. Providing answers does not contract us into lifetime support with the OP. Please read all of the advice, learn how to use all of the commands, and practice, until you achieve your intended result.

Comment: i tried this command at end of the query but not taking /XD C:\Users\garang\Documents\input_files\Advisory_rate....unable to exclude the folder from your earlier query

Comment: @RupeshShelar, please try to look at the problem logically; you cannot exclude `Advisory_Rate`, if it is also the source directory!

Comment: but for Advisory_Rate  we want /XF "Advisory Rate mapping.xlsx" "Quick_OPU_listing.xlsx" we want  only these two files to be there and not move