# xcopy - Cyclic copy error with exclude file

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I am trying to exclude a folder from xcopy to avoid a cyclic copy error, my script is doing this..

```
xcopy c:\test c:\test\myfolder\tmp /EXCLUDE:c:\test\myfolder\exclude.txt /E
```

My exclude.txt file has this inside..

```
c:\test\myfolder
\myfolder\
```

But it still giving me the cyclic copy error, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Try copying to somewhere outside of where you are copying from.

Comment: Thats precisely the opposite of what i am trying to achieve :) I need to copy to the same place

Comment: I was suggesting that to see if the error message goes away. I suspect `xcopy` is not the smartest program and it is tripping up on itself. It was a test - not a permanent solution.

Comment: __XCOPY__ makes the check for destination directory being a subdirectory of source directory without taking the entries in exclude list file into account. You could perhaps workaround this issue with `subst Z: c:\test\myfolder\tmp` and `xcopy.exe c:\test Z:\ /EXCLUDE:c:\test\myfolder\exclude.txt /E` and `subst Z: /D` (not verified by me).

Comment: What about using [`robocopy`](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)? like: `robocopy "C:\test" "C:\test\myfolder\tmp" /XD "C:\test\myfolder" /E`

Comment: Robocopy was a perfect fit, thanks for the advice!

Comment: @Mofi, your smart `subst` approach works fine, I just verified it!

Answer (score 3):

As [Mofi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3074564) already pointed out in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51177750/xcopy-cyclic-copy-error-with-exclude-file#comment89339598_51177750), the `/EXCLUDE` option of [`xcopy`](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) is regarded too late. Additionally, this feature is very poor -- refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42399461) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41016415) of mine (shameless self-promotion...).

Let me recommend to use [`robocopy`](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) instead, which supports nice exclusion options:

```cmd
robocopy "C:\test" "C:\test\myfolder\tmp" /XD "C:\test\myfolder" /E
```

Answer (score 1):

Going on from aschipfl advice in the comments, I solved this by using RoboCopy with the following...

```
robocopy C:\test C:\test\myfolder\tmp /XD myfolder
```