# XCOPY - How to exclude a certain file name?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, xcopy

This is my current xcopy command:

```
xcopy C:\SourceCodeOld\Release\"Source Code"\*.vb C:\SourceCodeNew\"Source Code"\ /S /Y /R
```

In **several** subfolders, I have a file named "AssemblyInfo.vb". How can I exclude it from being copied?

Comment: Type `xcopy /?` and look at the `/EXCLUDE` paramater.

Comment: 1. Your quotation style is terrible, always quote the whole paths: `xcopy /S /Y /R "C:\SourceCodeOld\Release\Source Code\*.vb" "C:\SourceCodeNew\Source Code\"`. 2. Type `xcopy /?` into Command Prompt and read the output!

Comment: How about this for an idea? Don't use `xcopy.exe`, use `Robocopy.exe` instead. Robocopy was released as a successor to xcopy, way back in Windows NT, and as such there is rarely a need to use xcopy. If you open a Command Prompt window, type `robocopy /?`, and press the `[ENTER]` key, you'll see that it has options to eXclude Files and Directories matching given names/paths/wildcards. i.e. `/XF file [file]...`, `/XD dir [dir]...`. Using this allows you to exclude directly from the command, without having to pre-create a file with one or more names/paths/wildcards.

Answer (score 2):

There is an `/EXCLUDE` option of [`xcopy`](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html), which allows to specify (the path to) a text file that contains partial file paths/names one per line (note also the fixed quotation):

```cmd
xcopy /S /Y /R /I /EXCLUDE:exclude.txt "C:\SourceCodeOld\Release\Source Code\*.vb" "C:\SourceCodeNew\Source Code"
```

with `exclude.txt` being in the current working directory and containing:

```cmd
AssemblyInfo.vb
```

However, the implementation of the `/EXCLUDE` option is terrible, because actually *all* files are excluded whose absolute source paths contain any of the given strings at *any* position (in a case-insensitive manner). Moreover, you cannot even use [wildcards](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html) in these strings. Furthermore, you cannot provide a quoted path to the exclusion text file to protect potential spaces or special characters. (Refer also to [this related answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42399461).)

---

I strongly recommend to use the [`robocopy` command](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html), whose exclusion options are more mature:

```cmd
robocopy "C:\SourceCodeOld\Release\Source Code" "C:\SourceCodeNew\Source Code" "*.vb" /S /XF "AssemblyInfo.vb"
```

This truly excludes only files whose names are `AssemblyInfo.vb`.

Comment: I'll vote for this because I was going to mention `robocopy` but I was too lazy `:p`

Comment: @Alexander `%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe` is deprecated since Windows Vista which means since more than 15 years. The successor is `%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe` which should be used for copying or moving multiple files with directory tree. __ROBOCOPY__ is more robust and has more options.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file `excludes.txt` and add the files to exclude to it (each in a new line)

```
AssemblyInfo.vb
anotherfile.vb
```

Then run your `xcopy` command using the `/EXCLUDE` parameter pointing to the file that contains the files to exclude:

```
xcopy "C:\SourceCodeOld\Release\Source Code\*.vb" "C:\SourceCodeNew\Source Code\" /EXCLUDE:excludes.txt /S /Y /R
```

To see the various options available for the `/EXCLUDE` parameter, run `xcopy /?`